# finding best way to bypassing password check process

Tags: ollydbg

i am working to openning or bypassing a password .  at first there is a password with 8 chracters ( letter,number , sign) that i attached a picture of password requst window i opened it by ollydbg and at first sete a bp on GetWindowsTextA and after i enterd worng password and checked out all code and all jumps  and wrote  comments in front of every jump  that i will explain they in following  and  seted a bp on every jump that it did do

in second step
i entered correct pass and i checked out all code and all jumps and wrote comments in front of every jump  that i will explain they in following and seted a bp on every jump that it did do
so there are many diffrents  between them  that i will  attached a screen shot of bps
so whats your idea ? how i can bypassing  the password process?

```
              * : if the JMP did  do when  entered worng pass 
              Q : if JMP didnot  do when enterd worng pass

              + : if the JMP did  do when  entered correct pass 
              R : if the JMP didnot  do when  entered correct pass
```

[image: password requst window]

[image: bp window screenshot]

[image: bp window screensho]

Comment: Why do you think the password is embeded into .exe? Isn't the application used to interface with some device?

Comment: thanks for your reply    check process do in the program . yes the app  is an interface